# SQL Select Query Giving me duplicate columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to display information, but when I use INNER JOIN I am getting duplicate ID fields. My tables and query are below. I am getting duplicate columns for wrestlerID. could it be my PK constraints?

```
CREATE TABLE WRESTLER 
(
    WrestlerID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerFirst VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerLast VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerStyle CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    WrestleKilos NUMERIC(3,0) NOT NULL,
    WrestleMeters NUMERIC(3,2),
    WrestleCity VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerState CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerBirthdate Date,

    CONSTRAINT WRESTLER_PK PRIMARY KEY (WrestlerID)
);

CREATE TABLE CLUB 
(
    ClubID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Club VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CLUB_PK PRIMARY KEY (ClubID, WrestlerID),
    CONSTRAINT CLUB_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (WrestlerID) REFERENCES WRESTLER(WrestlerID)
);

CREATE TABLE SCHOOL 
(
    SchoolID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    School VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL,
    WrestlerID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SCHOOL_PK PRIMARY KEY (SchoolID, WrestlerID),
    CONSTRAINT SCHOOL_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (WrestlerID) REFERENCES WRESTLER(WrestlerID)
);

CREATE TABLE MEDAL 
(
    WrestlerID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    WorldMedal NUMERIC(4,0),
    CONSTRAINT MEDAL_PK PRIMARY KEY (WrestlerID, WorldMedal),
    CONSTRAINT MEDAL_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (WrestlerID) REFERENCES WRESTLER(WrestlerID)
);

SELECT
    t1.WrestlerID, t1.WrestlerFirst, t1.WrestlerLast,
    t2.WrestlerID, t2.School,
    t2.WrestlerID, t3.Club 
FROM
    WRESTLER t1 
INNER JOIN
    SCHOOL t2 ON t1.WrestlerID = t2.WrestlerID 
INNER JOIN
    CLUB t3 ON t1.WrestlerID = t3.WrestlerID;
```

Comment: With inner joins, you really don't need to select each `WrestlerID`.  Just `SELECT t1.WrestlerID, ...` and remove the others.

Comment: One of your tables probably has multiple values for the same WrestlerID.  Can 1 wresteler have more than one medal?  Probably why.

Comment: Thank you Jon, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing my query worked

```
SELECT
t1.WrestlerID, t1.WrestlerFirst, t1.WrestlerLast,
t2.School,
t3.Club FROM
WRESTLER t1 INNER JOIN
SCHOOL t2 on t1.WrestlerID = t2.WrestlerID INNER JOIN
CLUB t3 on t1.WrestlerID = t3.WrestlerID;
```